# How to anchor multiple/all section headers of a UITableView to the top?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have tableview with 3 sections (and 3 section headers). Now I want to anchor all section headers in a tableview to the top of the screen. By default, only the 'current' section is anchored to the top. However, if I am viewing the 3rd section I want both the 1st and 2nd section header anchored to the top of the screen.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: I think you will have to implement this as custom behaviour, I don't think there is a way from Apple to do such a thing (mainly because it probably leads to problems for table views with a lot of sections, where from a certain point the whole screen would be populated with headers..). So, you probably have to write a custom control for it.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite difficult (without doing a lot of code) to achieve that anchoring effect.
However, if the  intended result is to have an index table always visible, you should have a look at the method :

```
- sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:
```

(It returns)

> an array of strings that serve as the title of sections in the table
>   view and appear in the index list on the right side of the table view.
>   The table view must be in the plain style (UITableViewStylePlain). For
>   example, for an alphabetized list, you could return an array
>   containing strings “A” through “Z”.

(from Apple Documentation : UITableViewDataSource protocol reference)